# How to draw smooth graphics outside of a vanilla Activity with setContentView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-canvas

I have an interesting situation if someone can see what i'm doing wrong?  I have a class called TrackView below.  It essentially opens up a hole where you touch the screen to reveal a hidden background only at that touch point.  This all works great when I call it from setContentView(new TrackView(this)).  Graphics are fast and fluid.  If I use the exact same TrackView class in the manner below which is started from a service(why i'm using WindowManager), graphics are drawn very poorly and slow.  The structure of the view hierarchy in each case is identical.  I've also tried SurfaceView and the problem did not go away.

```
public class OverlayTesting
{
    private WindowManager wm;
    private LayoutInflater li;
    private RelativeLayout rl;
    private View v;
    private TrackView tv;

    public OverlayTesting(Context context)
    {
        wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        v  = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_overlay, null);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        tv = new TrackView(context);
        rl.addView(tv);
    }

    public void show()
    {
        wm.addView(rl, new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT));
    }

    private class TrackView extends View
    {
        Bitmap bitmapBase;
        Bitmap bitmapDefault;
        Bitmap bitmapUsed;
        Canvas canvasBase;
        Canvas canvasDefault;
        Canvas canvasUsed;
        Paint paint1;
        Paint paint2;
        int displayHeight;
        int displayWidth;
        int X = -100;
        int Y = -100;

        public TrackView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);

            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point point = new Point();

            display.getSize(point);
            displayWidth  = point.x;
            displayHeight = point.y;

            // create base background
            bitmapBase = Bitmap.createBitmap(displayWidth, displayHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvasBase = new Canvas(bitmapBase);
            canvasBase.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            // create overlays and masks
            bitmapDefault = Bitmap.createBitmap(displayWidth, displayHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvasDefault = new Canvas(bitmapDefault);
            canvasDefault.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            bitmapUsed = Bitmap.createBitmap(displayWidth, displayHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
            canvasUsed = new Canvas(bitmapUsed);

            // paint structures here

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            switch (ev.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    X = (int) ev.getX();
                    Y = (int) ev.getY();
                    invalidate();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    X = (int) ev.getX();
                    Y = (int) ev.getY();
                    invalidate();

                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            // refresh overlay with default bitmap and open new hole at XY
            // refresh overlay code here

            // refresh core view canvas showing only area at XY
            // draw canvas code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly this problem goes away when upgrading to Android Lollipop 5.0.2.  Chalking this up as a Google issue that they resolved.  This issue was witnessed on Jelly Bean and Kit Kat.  I'd still be curious if there is a better way to do what i'm doing.